# How do I publish the artifact generated from assemblyPackageDependency

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

So I use sbt-assembly and I use the assembly assemblyPackageDependency task with my build which generates a project-assembly-1.0.0-deps.jar and no matter what I do I cannot get it to publish this jar file. How do I do this please?

I've added this in and variants of this but to no avail. I can get the full fat jar which has source in there which I dont want because tht causes conflicts.

```
settings(.....)
++addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, assemblyPackageDependency), assemblyPackageDependency)
```

If someone could please tell me how to do this I would be highly appreciative .. and still have hair left ...

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so I've given up and moved to using the xerial/sbt-pack plugin instead. Custom task and away we go. Much faster and cleaner too :)

Answer (score 0):

I`m not shure, I understood your task right, but take a look at [sbt release plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) to publish artifacts

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `oneJarSettings` instead of `sbt-assembly`. You can go through the [link](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar) here for the reference.